# Remove rows that share multiple columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

data = {'sample': ['R1', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3', 'R3'],
    'number': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    'pos': [323, 323, 410, 71, 918],
    'type': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c']}

vars = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to remove rows where where the `sample`, `number` and `pos` fields exist in another row.

To do this I am incrementing the count of a `defaultdict` using the `sample`, `number` and `pos` fields as a key, and then removing rows where this count is `> 1`:

```
seen = defaultdict(int)
print vars

for index, variant in vars.iterrows():
    key = '_'.join([variant['sample'], str(variant['number']), str(variant['pos'])])
    seen[key] += 1
    if seen[key] > 1:
        print("Seen this before: %s" % key)
        vars.drop(index, inplace=True)

print vars
```

This works as expected but I feel like I am somewhat missing the point of pandas by iterating over rows like this. Is there a more panda-native way of achieving the same thing?

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't clear in the question. It's not as simple as removing duplicates as other columns in the df may have differing values. See update.

Comment: Sorry, then need `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['sample', 'number', 'pos'])`

Comment: @jezrael - brilliant - thanks!

Comment: And changed dupe for better match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
vars = vars.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).